# Splitting a csv with awk: how to consider returns?

Tags: awk

I have this file:

```
field1|field2|field3|f41;f42|f5
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5|
field1|field2|field3|f41;f42;f43|f5
```

I want to parse it and obtain:

```
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5
field1|field2|field3|f42|f5
...
```

In short make a subparsing according to the semicolumn in field 4.
My awk script is the following:

```
awk < myfile.txt -F\| '{ 
n=split($4,a,";");
print $1
for(i=0; ++i <= n;)
print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"a[i]"|"$5"|"; 
}'
```

it works, anyway for lines not ending with "|" I get the first character of the following line disappearing! 
For example, given that file I get:

```
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5
ield1|field2|field3|f42|f5
```

I think it is due to the fact there is no "|" at the end of the line.
Is there a way to tell awk to consider the carriage return?

Comment: It's not entirely clear how your input maps to your desired output. Could you edit your example to make it clearer, adding some more explanation?

Comment: what character is disapearing? I cannot see difference between my code and yours at work, I have no problems, neither adding a | after some lines in myfile.tx

Comment: awk always considers the carriage return. that´s the way it always works with the input file. It´s difficult to understand what you need

Comment: are you using unix/linux? did u checked if your file has strange endline characters on some lines with vi turning on the "set list" option?

Comment: Added an example, anyway I am on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't write your for loops using some wacky syntax like `for(i=0; ++i <= n;)` as it just obfuscates your code (e.g. we need to think if `i` would be 0 or 1 first time through that loop since it's not clearly stated). Simply write them as they are intended to be written `for (init;condition;increment)`: `for(i=1;i <= n;i++)`.
2. Don't redirect input to awk, e.g. `awk < file 'script'`, just let awk open the file `awk 'script' file` so you always have access to `FILENAME` in your scripts.
3. Don't add spurious semi-colons throughout your script - this is not `C`.
4. Don't print a hard-coded field separator multiple times, e.g. `print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"a[i]"|"$5`, use OFS as designed instead: `OFS="|";...;print $1,$2,$3,a[i],$5`.
5. Don't use strings in a regexp context unless you have an excellent reason to do so as they just obfuscate, complicate and reduce efficiency of the code, e.g. instead of `split($4,a,";")` you should use `split($4,a,/;/)`.
6. Use white space/indentation, it is surprisingly cheap.

So step 1 is to rewrite your script:

```
awk < myfile.txt -F\| '{ 
n=split($4,a,";");
print $1
for(i=0; ++i <= n;)
print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"a[i]"|"$5"|"; 
}'
```

as:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    n=split($4,a,/;/)
    print $1
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        print $1, $2, $3, a[i], $5, "" 
}
' myfile.txt
```

From that, just by fixing your `for` loop syntax we can now clearly see that you are printing the first field twice, the first time on a line of it's own, so we can immediately change that to:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    n=split($4,a,/;/)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        print $1, $2, $3, a[i], $5, ""
}
' myfile.txt
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5|
field1|field2|field3|f42|f5|
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5|
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5|
field1|field2|field3|f42|f5|
field1|field2|field3|f43|f5|
```

So - is that what you wanted? Unfortunately you used the same values for the same field positions on all input lines so we can't tell which output lines/fields are coming from which input lines/fields and you didn't post your full expected output so we can't tell if the above is the expected output or not. It's also not clear if you really want to always print an empty field at the end of every output line or not or whether or not you really want to hard-code the number of output fields.

Oh, and if characters are disappearing in your output it's because you have control-Ms or some other spurious control characters in your input file. Use `cat -v` to see them and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them if they are control-Ms.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really useful tips! Anyway that still doesn't solve my problem..please check out my added example.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
    awk -F"|" '{n=split($4,a,";"); for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ print $1FS$2FS$3FS a[i] FS $5}}' file.dat
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5
field1|field2|field3|f42|f5
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5
field1|field2|field3|f41|f5
field1|field2|field3|f42|f5
field1|field2|field3|f43|f5
```